# How stop jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a div/box that i can move with the arrow keys.
Then i want the div/box to "fall down a hole" when comes to a specific point, and after that go back to start. It is no problem maiking the div/box fall but when i reset it i keep falling.

i use `anmimate()` for the fall and `css()` for the reset like this:

```
    if(parseInt(canvas.css('left'), 10) <= -220) {
        box.delay(250).animate({bottom: '0'}, 500)
    }

    if(parseInt(box.css('bottom'), 10) == 0) {
        canvas.animate({left: '0'}, 2000)
    }

    if((parseInt(box.css('bottom'), 10) == 0) && (parseInt(canvas.css('left'), 10) == 0)) {
        box.css('bottom', '100px');
    }
```

And i have made a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3qeD/)**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Here -> http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know `JQuery` have an .stop() method to stop animations, [there](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) you can take a look to this method
in the `JQuery` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the timeout. Many animation events are added in the queue. So it is executing all the events. If you increase the timeout, you can see the difference.

Btw, to stop all the events and clearing the queue, you can use `box.clearQueue().stop();`

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3qeD/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello my fellow computer enthusiast, i got a look on your fiddle, the answer was interesting:

Original version:

```
if(parseInt(canvas.css('left'), 10) <= -220) {
    box.delay(250).animate({bottom: '0'}, 500)
}
```

My Version:

```
if(parseInt(canvas.css('left'), 10) <= -220 && ready) {
    ready = false;
    box.delay(250).animate({bottom: '0'}, 500, function(){
        ready = true;
    });
}
```

In my version you have to add the variable ready on the start of the js code (var ready = true;), and set it to true.

The reason why this happens is because on your original version the if condition was true everytime during the animation, so JS runs it a lot of times before completes.

I know my solution is not the mos elegant one, but is only for educational purposes.

Regards.

PD: sorry my engrish so bad.

Comment: Look on the .animate() function, im using a callback to set ready to true AFTER the function ends.